# Как показать/спрятать блок при клике по кнопке?

Tags: jquery

Подскажите как дополнить код, что бы повторный клик по кнопке прятал блок.
Вот мой код на jquery

```js
$('.btn-map').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.list__routes').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
.btn-map {
  border: 3px solid rgb(62, 172, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 153, 255);
  font-family: $Lato;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.list__routes > .list__item {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.list__routes {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px;
  display: none;
}
.list__link {
  color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  font-family: $LatoLight;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  &: hover, &: focus {
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn-map" href="#">Маршруты</a>
<ul class="list__routes">
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#" class="list__link">Каменск-Баяндай</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#" class="list__link">Оса-Заршина</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#" class="list__link">Туристический маршрут</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#" class="list__link">Красоты Байкала</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#" class="list__link">Рыбалка в Листвянке</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#" class="list__link">Веломаршрут</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

сейчас при клике по кнопке блок появляется, как добавить событие что бы при повторном клике - блок прятался? Спасибо.

Comment: .toggle в помощь http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @C.Raf.T, это если бы он css класс добавлял тогда да, просто и элегантно. А так необходимо проверить значение свойства `display`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('.btn-map').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.list__routes').toggleClass('on');
});
```

```css
.btn-map {
  border: 3px solid rgb(62, 172, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 153, 255);
  font-family: $Lato;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.list__routes > .list__item {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.list__routes {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px;
  display: none;
}
.list__link {
  color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  font-family: $LatoLight;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  &: hover, &: focus {
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.list__routes.on {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn-map" href="#">Маршруты</a>
<ul class="list__routes">
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#" class="list__link">Каменск-Баяндай</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#" class="list__link">Оса-Заршина</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#" class="list__link">Туристический маршрут</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#" class="list__link">Красоты Байкала</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#" class="list__link">Рыбалка в Листвянке</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#" class="list__link">Веломаршрут</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с анимацией

```
$('.btn-map').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.list__routes').slideToggle();
});
```

Вариант как есть:

```
$('.btn-map').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.list__routes').is(':visible') ? $('.list__routes').hide() : $('.list__routes').show();
});
```